# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'route.key') from react navigation documentation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I copied code from React Navigation's documentation into my project after something I wrote didn't seem to work. But I still got the same error: `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'route.key')`

This is the code:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack'
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs'
import { Text } from 'react-native'

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator()
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator()

function Home() {
    return (
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen name="Feed" component={() => { return <Text>Feed</Text>}} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    )
  }
  
export default function App() {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator>
                <Stack.Screen
                name="Home"
                component={Home}
                options={{ headerShown: false }}
                />
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    )
}
```

It's almost the same as the same code as the one in the [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators) but doesn't seem to work. Any idea why?

Comment: created a snack, your code seems to work for me... [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@manuelwerder/navigationtest). Am I missing something?

Comment: Issue is not with this piece of code.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have the correct versions in your package.json file. I encountered this error when using @react-navigation/native-stack v6 and everything else v5. Sticking consistently to the v5 docs solved the issue for me :)